# Execute script in Sublime Text 2 (cmd + r in Textmate)

Tags: textmate

In Textmate I can use CMD + R to run a script (e.g .rb or a shell script). How do I do that in Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 0):

There is a build command with CMD + B shortcut.